# Completed 500 internal server error Devise Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise for authentication and have pushesd my code to heroku. However when I try to sign up with an already existing email Id, instead of coming as a validation error, it throws a 500 internal server error!

Clearly in logs it shows that it has found an existing user, but it throws the 500 internal server error entry before this.

What is the problem?

Comment: sorry , the error is coming after it checks that there is an existing user. Please let me know what is your analysis..

Comment: Post you code and logs.. BTW, you should try replicating the issue on local